# Applescript multiple "tell Application"

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I need to write a script that will launch the action in Photoshop and then execute the save command, but only the first part of the script is launched.
Executed only "tell app Photoshop" do action, then stuck...
Both scripts work separately

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
        do action "1 layer" from "To png"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
            key code 48
            key code 48
            key code 48
            key code 48
            key code 48
            key code 126
            key code 35
            key code 45
            key code 5
            key code 76
            key code 76
            key code 76
    end tell
return input
end run
```

Comment: GUI scripting via System Events will only target the frontmost application - is the Photoshop UI activated?

Comment: yes, but system events script is not starting

Comment: As @red_menace said, bring Photoshop to the foreground, even if it’s already there, using an `activate` command.  As for the apparent failure to start you believe you might be seeing from System Events, I have a feeling it started, did what you asked, and went back to bed before you had time to notice anything. I suspect `do action` is an “asynchronous” command, in that it might not wait for Photoshop to complete the action before the rest of the AppleScript continues to execute.